# Losing PHP sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a codeigniter app that makes extensive use of sessions, specifically using database sessions.

A few weeks ago, we had a user that reported an issue in that the app kept losing his session - he would try perform an action, and the session would be lost and he would be forced to keep logging in again. In the end, we figured out that this was due to him being on wireless broadband, and as soon as he switched to a fixed line, his problems went away completely.

Today, we had another user reporting the same problem - he is a (reportedly fast) wireless broadband connection, and he continually loses his session.

I've no idea on where to even begin...

Comment: How do you identify a session? Based upon what parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually discovered that this was due to a bug in the CI framework: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/154

Answer (score 2):

I have some suggestions regarding where to begin :)

1. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

   Since you said ***extensive use of sessions***, well ..

   > Note: Cookies can only hold 4KB of data, so be careful not to exceed
   >   the capacity.
2. `application/config/config.php` session config:

   ```
   $config['sess_expiration']      = 900;   // Inactive for too long?
   $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE; // Close his browser?
   $config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE; // IP renew accidentally or what?
   ```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: As I said, using DB sessions, so the cookie size is not significant. The other config vars are not relevant either. We have since found out that the user being logged out only happens on a specific controller/method...but there is no logical reason for why this one is different. Trying to figure that out now...